# Flatten array joining keys with values

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have this multidimensional array:

```
$array = array(
    'user1' => array('Miguel'),
    'user2' => array('Miguel', 'Borges', 'João'),
    'user3' => array(
        'Sara', 
        'Tiago' => array('Male')
    )
);
```

I want it flatten, transformed into:

```
$new_array = array(
    'user1.Miguel',
    'user2.Miguel',
    'user2.Borges',
    'user2.João',
    'user3.Sara',
    'user3.Tiago.Male',
);
```

**Important:**

- The keys are very important to me. I want them concatenated,
  separated by periods.
- It should work with any level of nesting.

Thank you!

Comment: Have your array always 3 levels? [here](https://eval.in/88216) is a quick solution for three level, but this should be do recursively

Comment: Have you tried anything, or are you wanting someone else to do your work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though not explicitly stated in your question, it seems that you need to concatenate the string keys and ignore the integer keys (which may be easily achieved with `is_string($key)`). And since you need your code to “work with any level of nesting,” a recursive function would serve your purpose best:

```
function array_flatten_key($arr){
$_arr = array();
    foreach($arr as $key => $val){
        if(is_array($val)){
            foreach(array_flatten_key($val) as $_val){
            $_arr[] = is_string($key) ? $key.".".$_val : $_val;
            }
        }
        else{
        $_arr[] = is_string($key) ? $key.".".$val : $val;
        }
    }
return $_arr;
}

$new_array = array_flatten_key($array);
print_r($new_array);
```

The output will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => user1.Miguel
    [1] => user2.Miguel
    [2] => user2.Borges
    [3] => user2.João
    [4] => user3.Sara
    [5] => user3.Tiago.Male
)
```